# What would happen if I accidentally connected the neutral and ground wires?

Tags: wiring

I was converting a fluorescent light fixture to LED. With the breaker off, I removed the ballast, then connected the hot wire to all the wires at one end of the fixture with a wire nut and connected the neutral to the wires at the other end of the fixture. By mistake, I also connected the ground wire. Before installing the LED's, I reset the breaker and flipped on the switch. Everything else on the circuit went off. I disconnected all of the wires in the fixture, then,  reset the breaker and the circuit was still off. I replaced the breaker, as I had thought before it might be faulty and still nothing. What might have happened by connecting the neutral and ground? Everything else in the house is working fine.

Comment: ballast might have suffered

Comment: Do you have an ordinary single-handle breaker, or one with a test button or indicator LED (latter type may be GFCI, AFCI, or combination)? Is there any chance this fixture is protected by a GFCI outlet somewhere? (If the fixture is in a garage, unfinished basement, bathroom, laundry room, or maybe a kitchen this is more likely.)

Comment: Pictures of both ends where you've made your connections would really help.

Comment: There is a possibility that you may have melted a cable, if it was undersized.

Comment: Neutral and ground are usually bonded together in the panel, so in some situations nothing at all would happen. I agree that a gfci trip is the most likely explanation

Comment: Connecting ground to neutral is an old hack done by lazy people when the neutral wire is broken.  Besides it being unsafe, illegal, against code, it should work/not cause problems with the circuit working, except if gfci is on the circuit.